# How to keep search value on Select component

Tags: reactjs, select

I've been updated And to 4.7.0 and it seems searchValue property is removed from API (actually it still exists but doesnt work properly). My issue is I have to keep the searched value within Select component, do you have any ideea how to approach that?

Thank you!

Comment: what's updated to 4.7.0?

Comment: add sample code for guide